# Round Special Price displayed in Catalogue pages (Product Listing Pages) - Magento 2.3.2

Tags: price, discount, magento2.3.2, rounding

Magento 2.3.2 - I have set discount through Catalog Price Rule. And so in Catalog pages (Product Listing Pages)

**there are two Prices displayed**

> 1) Regular Price
>   2) Special Price (discounted Price).

**My Problem is - Special Price is appearing in digit. i.e. Regular Price is 355.00 while Special Price is 312.40**
**I want to Round this Special Price** as 312.00.
How to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP **floor() Function** for rounding price.

```
  $floored_price = floor($special_price);
```

Example:

[image]

Hope this help you, Thank you

Comment: i am new to this pl.let me know name of file & location of file with code to update.

Comment: which page you want to change price?

Comment: Catalog pages (Product Listing Pages)

Comment: can you please upload listing page screenshot

Comment: app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme-classification}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml   try this

Comment: code please for final_price.phtml

Comment: how to round Special price - below is my code 

<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: no it is displaying 0

Comment: your actual code is working ?

Comment: Yes

it is displaying like

Special Price ₹396.00
Regular Price ₹450.00

But with your code

0
Regular Price ₹450.00

Comment: ohh  fine , it will display two amount right ? , and you need to change special price only , right ?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: No it is not working

I want to round Special Price...

it is displaying like

Special Price ₹312.40 Regular Price ₹355.00

Comment: Instead of Special Price ₹312.40 it should be Special Price ₹312.00

Comment: <?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
  <span class="special-price">
   <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ 

     echo $block->renderAmount(floor($finalPriceModel->getAmount()), 
      [ 'display_label' => __('Special Price'),
      'price_id' => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
      'price_type' => 'finalPrice', 'include_container' => true, 'schema' => $schema ]); 
    ?>

Comment: no it is not working..

nothing display.. blank page..

Comment: no it is not available

Comment: @Paresh please upload your code screenshot ,Please

Comment: full code of final_price.phtml is default code of magento 2.3.2 installation only... no change I made. (app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme-classification}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_phtml)

Comment: okay i'm working on it ,wait

Comment: search this line in your code .. 
<span class="price"><?php echo $helper->getcurrencySymbol().''.$deal_final_price_amount; ?></span>

Comment: no such line...

Comment: Below is complete code in parts...

<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>

Comment: which theme your using

Comment: blank theme

/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: brother , your using magento default LUMA theme ?

Comment: actually custom theme ... but having parent theme ... blank theme ... 

blank theme /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: which team your activate ?

Comment: it is custom made ... pnc but having parent as blank and as I said files are from 

blank theme /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: however you can consider it as Luma theme.... also and make your code accordingly..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97664/discussion-on-answer-by-shafeel-sha-round-special-price-displayed-in-catalogue-p).

Answer (score 0):

Used [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) Function

```
<?php
echo(round(0.60) . "<br>");  //output 1
echo(round(0.50) . "<br>");  //output 1
echo(round(0.49) . "<br>");  //output 0
echo(round(-4.40) . "<br>"); //output -4
echo(round(-4.60));          //output -5
?>
```

Comment: i am new to this pl.let me know name of file & location of file with code to update.

Comment: which page you want please attach screen shot

Comment: Catalog pages (Product Listing Pages)

Comment: using theme or module ?